# Ensure one instance of an applescript is running

Tags: macos, applescript, screensaver

There is an screensaver that will launch scripts in OS X - which is great, but the problem I am having is that it launches multiple copies of the script. Is there a simple way to ensure that only one copy of this script is running at a time?

Answer (score 1):

[John Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/) wrote a [post](http://daringfireball.net/2006/10/how_to_tell_if_an_app_is_running#fnr1-2006-10-10) on something very similar to this a while back. Long story short, you would just wrap the entire thing in a block similar to the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    count (every process whose name is "BBEdit")
end tell
```

replacing "BBEdit" with your app name, and then launch only if the count is 0.

Comment: I tried something like this using this [script](http://www.perceptiveautomation.com/wiki/doku.php?id=applescript_snippit) as a base. I couldn't get it to work though. I don't think ps was seeing the applescript. IRT System Events seeing an individual applescript - I'll have to ask another question about that.

Comment: I think this approach is intended for applescripts saves as standalone applications ("Save As..." with "File Format: Application"). In that case, it will launch as it's own process.